# iOS - SplitViewController alternative?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am looking to change the width of the master view in a `UISplitViewController` in an App Store acceptable way. Changing private `_masterColumnWidth` property works in principle, but I'm assuming it will get rejected if submitted to the App Store.

I looked into a commonly recommended alternative, [`MGSplitViewController`](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/), but it hasn't been updated in a while, and at least in my testing with iOS 6+ behaves a little sporadically - does not always calculate the views' geometry correctly as you keep rotating the device. Are there any other alternatives, considering this is pretty much the only change to the `UISplitViewController` that I need to implement?

Comment: Make you own. Shouldn't be too hard using container views.